# Need help with NestList

Tags: warning-messages, iterators

> NestList::intnm: Non-negative machine-sized integer expected at position 3 in NestList[#1 + t&, 0, 8.].

What does the above error mean and how can I refer to result of `NestList`?

[image]

```
m = 1266.5;
k = 50;
Pt = {{0, 0}, {.2, 1000}, {.4, 0}, {.6, -1000},{.8, 0}};
ListLinePlot[Pt]

ω =  N[Sqrt[(k*1000)/m], 5];
Round[T = (2*N[Pi, 5])/ω, 0.1];
Δt = Round[T/10, 0.1]
p1 = Interpolation[Pt, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
P1 = p1[Δt];
NestList[# + Δt &, Part[Pt, 1, 1], Round[FixedPoint[(#) &, (Part[Pt, 5, 1]/Δt)]]]
```

Comment: Exactly what the error message it says: the 3rd argument of `NestList` should be an integer (like `8`), not a floating point number (like `8.`). You can use `Round` to convert floats to integers. I'm also unclear about what the `FixedPoint` is supposed to accomplish here. And for future reference: please post code, not images. Make it as easy as possible for people to copy your code and try it out for themselves.

Comment: thank you very much. Can you answer the second part of my question as well? how can I refer to Result of NestList for example , I need at first 0.1 in a Formula and than 0.2 and 0.3,how can I references that

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Why do it with `NestList` when the much simpler `Δt Range[Round[Pt[[5, 1]]/Δt]]` works.

Comment: @ScottConstantine If you want to save your result to refer to it later, you'll have to store it in a variable (which, judging from your code, you already know how to do).